# Is softmax an activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, softmax

Is softmax an activation function? Because it is usually used in the output layer, why?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is by the common defintion. E.g. wikipedia writes:

> In artificial neural networks, the activation function of a node defines the output of that node given an input or set of inputs.

[(Source.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function)

Also, contrary to what you write, softmax is also used as an intermediary sometimes. E.g. for the last layer before a linear layer or in switching recurrent systems.

- De Brébisson, Alexandre, et al. "Artificial neural networks applied to taxi destination prediction." arXiv preprint arXiv:1508.00021 (2015).
- Becker-Ehmck, Philip, Jan Peters, and Patrick Van Der Smagt. "Switching Linear Dynamics for Variational Bayes Filtering." arXiv preprint arXiv:1905.12434 (2019).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, that depends on your working definition - who wants to know and why.

Broadly, it's a function that takes a bunch of inbound signals and determines the outbound signal of the neuron, so it absolutely is an activation function.

The reason it usually shows up only at final layers is that it behaves in an unusual way - it normalizes all the inputs relative to their sum. That behavior is very useful for classification layers, not so much for the guts of the hidden layers most of the time.